# Getting an error while using copy activity (polybase) in adf to copy parquet files in ADLS gen2 to Azure synapse table

Tags: parquet, azure-synapse, polybase, azure-data-factory

My source is parquet files in ADLS gen2. All the parquet files are part files of size 10-14 MB. The total size should be around 80 GB

Sink is Azuresynapse table.

Copy method is Polybase. Getting below error within 5 sec of execution like below:

ErrorCode=PolybaseOperationFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Error happened when loading data into SQL Data Warehouse. Operation: 'Create external table'.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException,Message=External file access failed due to internal error: 'Error occurred while accessing HDFS: Java exception raised on call to HdfsBridge_IsDirExist. Java exception message:
HdfsBridge::isDirExist - Unexpected error encountered checking whether directory exists or not: AbfsRestOperationException: Operation failed: "This request is not authorized to perform this operation.", 403, HEAD, URL',Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider,SqlErrorNumber=105019,Class=16,ErrorCode=-2146232060,State=1,Errors=[{Class=16,Number=105019,State=1,Message=External file access failed due to internal error: 'Error occurred while accessing HDFS: Java exception raised on call to HdfsBridge_IsDirExist. Java exception message:
HdfsBridge::isDirExist - Unexpected error encountered checking whether directory exists or not: AbfsRestOperationException: Operation failed: "This request is not authorized to perform this operation.", 403, HEAD,

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this error due to failed authentication, check whether the authorization header and/or signature is wrong.
For example, create the scope credential using your ADLS Gen2 storage account access key:

```
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL [MyADLSGen2Cred] WITH
  IDENTITY='user',
  SECRET='zge . . . 8V/rw=='
```

The external data source is created as follows:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE [MyADLSGen2] WITH (
  TYPE=HADOOP,
  LOCATION='abfs://myblob@pabechevb.dfs.core.windows.net',
  CREDENTIAL=[MyADLSGen2Cred])
```

You can specify wasb instead of abfs, and if you're using SSL, specify it as abfss. Then the external table is created as follows:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [dbo].[ADLSGen2] (
  [Content] varchar(128))
WITH (
  LOCATION='/',
  DATA_SOURCE=[MyADLSGen2],
  FILE_FORMAT=[TextFileFormat])
```

You can find additional information in my book "Hands-On Data Virtualization with Polybase".

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it was an authentication issue. Thanks for the help